# Qt ComboBox : SQLite Merge Two Table

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, combobox

I need some help. This is the code for my normal combobox where it will display Customer information by choosing the Customer ID. How I can display data from the other table (LOAN) & also information from CUSTOMER table together by customer id on the combobox.

```
void LoanRequest::on_comboBox_custID_activated(const QString &arg1)
{    
    Login conn;

    if (!conn.connOpen())
    {
      qDebug()<<"Failed to open the database.";
      return;
    }

   conn.connOpen();
   QSqlQuery qry;

   if(qry.exec("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE Cust_ID='"+arg1+"'"))        
   {
      //database table, my 2 table that i want to merge
      //LOAN : loanid, loan_type, custid,loan_status
      //CUSTOMER : custid, custname, custic,custaddress, custtelno

      while(qry.next())
      {
        ui->label_name->setText(qry.value(2).toString());
        ui->label_icno->setText(qry.value(3).toString());
        ui->label_telno->setText(qry.value(5).toString());
      }
  }
  else
  {
     QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("Error"),qry.lastError().text());
  }      
  conn.connClose();
}
```

Comment: You don't know how to make SELECT from two tables? Or you don't know how to show result in combobox?

Comment: @demonplus both. I usually use only one table, so i didn't know how to work with two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if(qry.exec("SELECT CUSTOMER.custname, \
            CUSTOMER.custic,CUSTOMER.custtelno,LOAN.loanid \ 
            FROM CUSTOMER JOIN LOAN WHERE CUSTOMER.custid = LOAN.custid \
            AND Cust_ID='"+arg1+"'"))        
{
  //database table, my 2 table that i want to merge
  //LOAN : loanid, loan_type, custid,loan_status
  //CUSTOMER : custid, custname, custic,custaddress, custtelno

  while(qry.next())
  {
    ui->label_name->setText(qry.value(2).toString());
    ui->label_icno->setText(qry.value(3).toString());
    ui->label_telno->setText(qry.value(5).toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So how to show the result to the label as previously i use indexing, but now i'll be using 2 different table?

Comment: You mean result from query? index zero is CUSTOMER.custname, index 1 is CUSTOMER.custic ...